# Why are the default namespace behaviors for loaded packages in R and Python different?

Tags: python, r, namespaces

In Python, using default behavior, if you want to use a function `fun` from a loaded package `package` you always have to designate it as belonging to some new/different namespace when calling it, i.e. `package.fun()`. If you have installed but not loaded the package, there is no way to call the function at all (as far as I am aware).

In R, using default behavior, if you want to use a function `fun` from a loaded package `package` you can use the global namespace without any issue, i.e. `fun()` calls `fun`. If the package is installed but not loaded, you can *still* call it by designating a new/different namespace, i.e. `package::fun()`.

**Question:** If one way of managing namespaces from installed packages is better than the other, then why don't both programming languages use the same default behaviors?

I have read a lot of people say that the default Python namespace behavior is great, yet I have never seen someone who uses R feel compelled to defend the default behavior of R, even though it is so much different from the default behavior of Python, which is supposed to be great.

Maybe the difference is that there isn't a Python version of CRAN? As a beginner, I don't really see how this is relevant, but CRAN does relate to packages at least. Although I thought that not all R packages on Bioconductor are also available on CRAN.

**Examples:** As more concrete examples: in Python

```
import numpy
numpy.array()
```

works, but neither

```
import numpy
array()
```

nor

`numpy.array()`

works.

While in R, both

`library(ggplot2)
 ggplot()`

and

```
ggplot2::ggplot()
```

work.

Comment: what if you do this - from numpy import *

Comment: I don't know how python works but as I understand (and I'll be happy to be corrected) library doesn't really load everything from the package. Elements are loaded when you need them. If you don't call library and call :: notation, I would suppose this data will be cleared at the end of the operation. Also, can you handle maggritr type operators in python? For the rest I suppose it's a trade-off between consistency, readability, and ease of use.

Comment: Why you are comparing specifically python with R? Every language has its own ways of dealing with extensions/modules/libraries/whatever, so it's not surprising at all to have different languages behaving differently in this matter.

Comment: @nicola Well Python and R are supposed to be the "top data science languages". So I am trying to re-familiarize myself with Python while learning R, in order to be able to use both. I agree that it's not surprising, I guess what I'm surprised about is why no one complains about or defends R's behavior, considering how much praise is given for Python's behavior. Since Python's behavior is so good for data science, why do people using R for data science put up with the exact opposite behavior from R?

Comment: Neither python nor R have been conceived and developed for "data science", since data science didn't even exist at the time. The fact that they are now (also) used for the same purpose is totally irrelevant. About people complaining or praising I can't tell anything; just ask them why. I personally can't see much to complain or praise about how a language load libraries; I'd just learn the ways to do it.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that they "should" or "shouldn't" be used for the same purpose, my point just is that they often nowadays _are_ used for similar purposes, and therefore are frequently compared with one another. https://www.r-bloggers.com/namespaces-and-name-conflicts/

Answer (score 1):

Different languages behave differently and there is no "best" behavior across all languages because the context (consistency, tradition, principle of least surprise) matters. Python is just being consistent with its philosophy (and actual fact) that everything is an object. A module is an object. If you want to access an attribute of an object, you use the dot notation. If an object is not found (in your third `numpy` example where you did not `import numpy`) you get a `NameError` which is also what you would expect from consistent behavior.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that packages (=modules?) are also objects in Python. And this is not the same in R? So the behavior is different because Python is more "object-based/centered" than R?

Comment: @Chill2Macht as an example. open the interpreter and type in `imort numpy; numpy` - it will say it's a module object. I don't know much about R, but apparently it's just designed differently.